# Parent Node in BST

Tags: efficiency, binary-search-trees

Is it a good idea to store a pointer to the parent node in a binary search rather than to find the parent node several times?

```
struct BSTNode
{
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    Node* parent;     //nullptr for root
    int data;
};
```

or

```
struct BSTNode
{
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    int data;
    Node* findParent(Node* root);
};
```

Comment: It depends on the application. No clear-cut answer.

Comment: That said, if space is not at premium, you probably don't lose much by having one more field in your data structure.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, since you don't define what criteria you would use for judging whether it is a "good idea" or what context you're using the data structure in.  As such, the only answers you're likely to get are "it depends" or answers that are a matter of opinion.